# How do select a radio button with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've tried `select();` `check();` and even `.selected = true;` but I still haven't gotten around to selecting that radio button. Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `checked` property:

```
element.checked = true;
```

**Reference**: [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement)

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type=radio id='r'>
<script>
document.getElementById('r').checked=true;
</script>
```

Use .checked

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could post your code and we could give you a more complete solution?

To check a radio button I'm pretty sure it's .checked = true;